# How to draw multipart geometries in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

[ol.interaction.Draw](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.interaction.Draw.html) has Point, LineString, Polygon, MultiPoint, MultiLineString, MultiPolygon and Circle as type options. What I couldn't figure out is how to actually draw e.g. a MultiPolygon containing several single polygons. [Here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ffsaefxr/) that console-logs a valid GeoJSON string, however, only containing one single polygon.

Relevant code:

```
// create draw interaction and add it to the map:
drawInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({ source:vectorSource, type:"MultiPolygon" });
map.addInteraction(drawInteraction);

// define GeoJSON format:
var formatGeoJSON = new ol.format.GeoJSON();

// set listener on "drawend":
drawInteraction.on("drawend", function(e) {
    // get feature:
    var feature = e.feature; 
    // clone feature:
    var featureClone = feature.clone();
    // transform cloned feature to WGS84:
    featureClone.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
    // get GeoJSON of feature:
    var geojson = formatGeoJSON.writeFeature(featureClone);
    // log:
    console.log(geojson);
});
```

Comment: You are overwriting `var geojson` instead of pushing a new polygon.

Comment: OK, I see! I tried `features.push(featureClone)` and `var geojson = formatGeoJSON.writeFeatures(features);`This, hovever, creates a FeatureCollection.

Comment: I guess you should use http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.geom.MultiPolygon.html#appendPolygon

Comment: So I need to explicitly create a MultiPolygon with `ol.geom.MultiPolygon` (by providing its coordinates) and then append each additional polygon with `appendPolygon`?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you doing something like:

```
var drawInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: vectorSource,
    type: "Polygon"
});
map.addInteraction(drawInteraction);

var multiPolygon = new ol.geom.MultiPolygon([]);
drawInteraction.on('drawend', function(e) {
    var
        feature = e.feature,
        poly = feature.getGeometry()
    ;
    multiPolygon.appendPolygon(poly);
    updateGeojson();
});
function updateGeojson(){
    var
        formatGeoJSON = new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        cloned = multiPolygon.clone()
    ;
    cloned.transform('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
    var geojson = formatGeoJSON.writeGeometry(cloned);
    console.info(geojson);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/epyuLy7x/

Comment: Thank you, Jonatas! I'm still wondering how  `ol.interaction.Draw` is intended for the use with type "MultiPolygon". But it's a nicely working solution!